# I want to delete the entire line if the second occurrence of a special character is followed by a specific character

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, sh

Ex: I want to delete the below two rows if the `*` appears after the second occurence of `:`.

```
/path/:456: * This entire line needs to be deleted

/auto/myfolder/:999 :               *  This entire line should get deleted
```

Note: `*` should be the first character after the second `:`,ignore spaces.

can anyone help me to make it work in a shell script using sed or grep ?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Can there be any more `:` ? So, can there be a line like `/path/:789: some data:* This entire line needs to be deleted` Otherwise this would work too: `awk -F: '!($3 ~ /\*/)' file_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed '/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[ \t]*\*/d' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` : starting at the beginning of the line
- `[^:]*:` : search for zero ore more(`*`) non `:` characters followed by `:`
- `[^:]*:` : same pattern as above to search for second `:`
- `[ \t]*` : any number of spaces of tabs
- `\*` : escaped `*`
- if pattern is found, apply the `d`(delete) command to the line

As `[^:]*:` is repeated, you can use `\{2\}` quantifier instead:

```
sed '/^\([^:]*:\)\{2\}[ \t]*\*/d' file
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i '/^[^:]*:[^:]*:[ \t]*\*/d' file
```

Comment: Thnks Le,can you please explain the regex ?

Comment: Do you know how to remove the comments with sed.

Comment: /path/:456: * This entire line needs to be deleted //This should be deleted too
/* single line comment */
/auto/myfolder/:999 :               *  This entire line should get deleted

Comment: c comments (/* */) and c++ comments (//) from a file wherever they appear in a file by using sed.Is is possible by using sed.

Comment: Code in comments is hard to read. Maybe you should ask another question for that.

Comment: Thanks for the help Le